# AngularJS : Iterating over a range (or group) of variables

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-app

**Update:** Please see the Scenario section below.

I have `<input>` tags like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 1" ng-model="mcanswer1"
        ng-disabled="mca1Disabled" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 2" ng-model="mcanswer2"
        ng-disabled="mca2Disabled" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 3" ng-model="mcanswer3"
        ng-disabled="mca3Disabled" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 4" ng-model="mcanswer4"
        ng-disabled="mca4Disabled" />
```

and then in the controller:

```
$scope.addQuestion = function() {
    // Some code
    if ($scope.mcanswer1 !== "") {
        list.append("<li>" + $scope.mcanswer1 + "</li>");
    }
    if ($scope.mcanswer2 !== "") {
        list.append("<li>" + $scope.mcanswer2 + "</li>");
    }
    if ($scope.mcanswer3 !== "") {
        list.append("<li>" + $scope.mcanswer3 + "</li>");
    }
    if ($scope.mcanswer4 !== "") {
        list.append("<li>" + $scope.mcanswer4 + "</li>");
    }
};
```

I know this is a poor way of iterating over these variables, but then what is the correct (i.e., AngularJS) way to do it?

### Scenario

I should have explained my setup better. My mistake.

On one side of my page I have a text area (for the question), 6 text fields (for the multiple choice answers; only 4 shown in the example above) and an "Add" button. When the user fills out the fields and hits the "Add" button, a `div` is added to the other side of the page with the question in a `p` tag, and the answers as an unordered list below. That's it. That's why the function is called `addQuestion`.

The user can repeat this procedure multiple times, thereby building up a set of questions. At this moment this is all I need to do. That is why I am iterating over the `$scope.mcanswerN` variables --- to use their values to show the question on the other side, then re-use them to fill-in the next question.

Comment: move the behaviour into the html, using ng-if/ng-show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing we can do is to group this models together and iterate it using `angular.forEach`

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 1" ng-model="obj.mcanswer1"
       ng-disabled="mca1Disabled" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 2" ng-model="obj.mcanswer2"
       ng-disabled="mca2Disabled" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 3" ng-model="obj.mcanswer3"
       ng-disabled="mca3Disabled" />
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Answer 4" ng-model="obj.mcanswer4"
       ng-disabled="mca4Disabled" />
```

**JS**

```
angular.forEach($scope.obj, function(val) {
        alert(val)
        // conditions
        if(val !== '') {
        }
    })
```

Note that I have used `obj.mcanswer1` in ng-model.

Comment: Why doesn't this `forEach` give me the variables `mcanswer1`, `mcanswer2` etc. in that order? Some times the order seems to change, especially if one or more of the in-between text fields have been left empty or just spaces.

Comment: @markvgti just log `$scope.obj` and check the order before iterating.

Comment: Because its an object not an array. The order of enumeration cannot be guaranteed. That is why `angular.forEach` is used and not the native array `forEach`. Angular with mutate its `forEach` behaviour to be able to iterate over multiple different types of objects.

Answer (score 2):

The angular way would be to build a model and simply bind your html to that model.

Your method name and what it appears to do seem to conflict, so i presume when you click a button you want to show answers not add a question.

Either way you would build an array that depicts your questions. something like:

```
$scope.questions = [{
    placeHolder: 'Answer 1',
    model: '',
    disabled: false
},{
    placeHolder: 'Answer 2',
    model: '',
    disabled: true
},{
    placeHolder: 'Answer 3',
    model: '',
    disabled: false
}];
```

You extend that further with variables to say is this answer correct etc. A variable that actually contains a question show show above the input.

then build you template

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="q in questions">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{q.placeHolder}}" ng-model="q.model" ng-disabled="q.disabled" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

You can then use that array and the model property to again do a seperate `ng-repeat` to show just the anwers. If you use a `answerCorrect` sort of flag you can filter that result to only show correct answers and apply a `answer-invalid` sort of class to the input.

You can then easliy extend your question by simply pushing a new object to your array and angular works out the rest.

See the fiddle showing it all.

http://jsfiddle.net/bcb1tg6d/2/

Hope that helps.

Comment: I am actually adding a question, with its multiple choice answers, it's just that I showed only the part about reading the text field values and adding them to the display area. Please see my **Scenario** explanation added to the question.

Comment: @markvgti Ive updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/bcb1tg6d/4/ If i understand correctly you just expand your model and template accordingly. So your question has an array of possible answers. You then bind to a property the selected answer to perform validation against. You could then easily modify the possible answers. The logic for validation requires small changes. Also adding new questions or removing them on the fly is just as easy. You don't need to use a select to display answers either. That was just for easy of use for demo purposes.

Answer (score 0):

To have a clear iteration you could use [lodash](http://lodash.com).

```
var nonEmptyKeys = _.keys(_.pick(_.pick($scope, ['mcanswer1', 'mcanswer2', 'mcanswer3', 'mcanswer4'], _.identity));
```

and then

```
_.each(nonEmptyKeys, function(key){
  list.append("<li>" + _.get($scope, key) + "</li>");
});
```

but hey, you can make it even shorter:

```
list.append( _.map(nonEmptyKeys, function(key){ return "<li>" + key + "</li>" ; }).join('') );
```